# Asynchronously reading and processing user input without delay or disruption of the main task

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm experiencing a weird niggly issue with bash:

I have the following for loop:

```
for i in {1..9999}
do
    printf '%s%04d' "(311) 399-" "$i"
    read -r -s -t 6 input
    #echo "x $input"
    if [ "$input" == "q" ] || [ "$input" == "Q" ] || [ "$input" == "x" ] || [ "$input" == "X" ] || [ "$input" == "p" ] || [ "$input" == "p" ]
    then
        #echo "1"
        break
    else
        #echo "2"
        printf '\n'
    fi
done
```

The loop itself works as expected. It prints out text like this:

```
(311) 399-0001
(311) 399-0002
(311) 399-0003
```

The problem is that the loop can't be exited. The idea was to have this continue to a maximum of 9999, but if the ENTER key was pressed, break the loop immediately. I was having issues getting IFS to work with "" being equated to ENTER, so I opted to choose a few letters a used wishing to exit the loop would probably press, such as Q, X, and P.

However, the loop would never exit when keys were pressed.

To debug, I added in the lines that are commented out above. To my surprise, nothing was printing out and it was always choosing route "2" - input was not being registered.

I've tried playing with the formatting of the read statement. When I change `read -r -s -t 6 "" input` to  `read -r -s -t 6 "" input`, I get a strange error:

```
(311) 399-9998/home/com/wopr.sh: line 923: read: `': not a valid identifier
x
2

(311) 399-9999/home/com/wopr.sh: line 923: read: `': not a valid identifier
x
2
```

I tried removing the `-r` part as well and the `-p` option but nothing has changed.

I have hundreds of other read statements in this and other scripts and this is the first issue I am having with any of them. What's causing the `input` variable to always be null?

**Workaround:**

I did figure out a workaround for this. A bit unconventional, but it does work, allowing ENTER to be pressed but not other characters. No input also does not equate to an ENTER:

```
for i in {1..9999}
do
    printf '%s%04d' "(311) 399-" "$i"
    time1=`date +%s`
    read -t 6 -s -r -p "" input
    time2=`date +%s`
    dif=$((time2-time1))
    if [ "$dif" == "6" ] && [ "$input" == "" ]
    then
        printf '\n'
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: `input variable to always be null?` - what does it mean for variables to "be null"? The variable can be unset or set. If set, it can be empty or notempty. What state is "be null"? What does `#echo "x $input"` after uncommenting show? Does `read` return with a zero exit status? Do you press "enter" key after entering your letter? And `[ "$input" == "p" ] || [ "$input" == "p" ]` is probably a typo, this whole `if` would look much simpler as `case "$input" in q|Q|x|X|p|P) break; ;;`. I think I would implement a background job for printing characters and other job for waiting for user input.

Comment: `[ "$input" = "" ]` or `[ -z "$input" ]` should work fine to detect hitting return without any other input.

Comment: @chepner The problem with this was that if nothing was entered, this would also be true, breaking the loop

Comment: @KamilCuk I use that same if style hundreds of other times throughout my scripts and it works, even with the double equals. The problem isn't there, it's the read statement, as the echoed variable is *empty*. You can see a bit of the output above at the end of my question. Nothing is echoed after the x, so there was nothing stored in input.

Comment: Did you write the script on Windows (eol = "\r\n" instead of "\n"). Does `less wopr.sh` show any weird characters?

Comment: @Bayou I do, but I change the encoding to Unix in N++. Also, I just figured out a workaround... not pretty, but it works!

Comment: @InterLinked I'm interested in the solution. Will you please update your answer? :-)

Comment: If you want to handle input asynchronously while still sticking to the 6s delay in the loop, not blocking the loop operations. Then you probably need to run a job for the input in the background, that transmit input to the main loop via a named pipe.

Comment: `"$dif" == "6"` the time calculation is strange, `read` returns a "exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded", just `if (( $? > 128 ))`.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation with Asynchronous reading of user quit key
and inter-task messaging.

@InterLinked, Looked like Bash robocalling, so here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Handle exit to cleanly dispose of resources
exit_trap() {
  # If there is a PID of the input_task
  if [[ -n ${input_pid:-} ]]; then
    # SIGnal the input_task to TERMinate
    kill 2>/dev/null -s TERM "${input_pid}" || true
    wait "${input_pid}" # Be sure it has stopped
    unset input_pid
  fi

  # Close/Free the message File Descriptor
  [[ -n ${msg_fd} ]] && exec {msg_fd}>&-

  # Purge the Temporary FIFO Directory
  [[ -n ${fifo_dir} && -d ${fifo_dir} ]] \
    && { rm -fr -- "${fifo_dir}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || true; }
}

# Install an exit handler for cleanup before exit
trap exit_trap EXIT ERR

# Create the Temporary FIFO Directory
# Create the FIFO device in it with name msg_fifo
# Assign the named File Descriptor msg_fd to the FIFO msg_fifo
fifo_dir="$(mktemp --directory)" \
  && msg_fifo="${fifo_dir}/msg_fifo" \
  && mkfifo "${msg_fifo}" \
  && exec {msg_fd}<>"${msg_fifo}"

# Run in the background to get user input, and eventually SIGnal an IO
# to the main loop, with a quit message that is just the integer value 1.
input_task() {
  local -- input
  while :; do
    read -r -s -N 1 input # Read exactly -N 1 character, -r raw, -s silent
    case "${input}" in
      [qQxXpP]) # POSIX Character class matching q, Q, x, X, p, P
        # Output the integer value 1 as the message content,
        # to the Named File Descriptor msg_fd
        echo >&${msg_fd} 1
        # SIGnal IO to the foreground task IO-trap handler,
        # that there is a message to read
        kill -s IO $$
        ;;
    esac
  done
}

# msg is the Message-Box variable. It Needs to be global,
# so it can be populated by the IO signal handler.
typeset -- msg=''

# Launch the input_task in the background, with the current stdio input &1.
input_task <&1 &

# Save the process ID of the background-running input_task.
typeset -- input_pid="$!"
# This is the IO message handler subscribed to the IO trap signal:
# It reads -u Named File Descriptor msg_fd, -r raw into the msg Message-Box variable
trap 'read -u ${msg_fd} -r msg' IO

# Now that the input_task is running in the background, and there is
# an IO trap handler to read the messages from the input_task...
# Here starts the main stuffs, not bothering with waiting, decoding,
# retrying user inputs, as all of it is done asynchronously by
# the background input_task.
typeset -i \
  area_code=311 \
  switch_code=399 \
  call_index_min=1 \
  call_index_max=9999 \
  call_freq=6

typeset -i \
  to_call \
  remaining_time
to_call=$((1 + call_index_max - call_index_min))
remaining_time=$((call_freq * to_call - 3600))

printf $'Calling a total of %d number(s), one per %ds.\n' \
  "${to_call}" \
  "${call_freq}"
printf $'Total time to complete calls: %()T.\n\n' "${remaining_time}"

while read -r line_number; do
  typeset -- phone_number='(area) switch-line'
  printf -v phone_number '(%03d) %03d-%04d' \
    "${area_code}" \
    "${switch_code}" \
    "${line_number}"
  printf $'%()T, %d to go, Calling: %s\n' \
    "${remaining_time}" \
    "${to_call}" \
    "${phone_number}"
  ((remaining_time -= call_freq, to_call--))
  # Wait call_freq seconds in the background,
  sleep "${call_freq}" &
  # to allow interruptions of the sleep,
  # when there is a message signaled by the IO trap
  # so it can quit immediately on receiving msg=1
  wait $!
  ((msg)) && {
    echo $"ABORT"
    break
  } # msg -eq 1, so break out of the loop
done < <(
  # Generate a scrambled list of line numbers
  sort \
    --random-sort \
    < <(
      seq \
        "${call_index_min}" "${call_index_max}"
    )
)
```

Sample output:

```
Calling a total of 9999 number(s), one per 6s.
Total time to complete calls: 16:39:54.

16:39:54, 9999 to go, Calling: (311) 399-4409
16:39:48, 9998 to go, Calling: (311) 399-2174
16:39:42, 9997 to go, Calling: (311) 399-3840
16:39:36, 9996 to go, Calling: (311) 399-4583
ABORT
```

Comment: The problem with reading 1 character is the read terminates before 6 seconds. I need to have 6 seconds between each iteration of the loop. So I need to figure out how to get  read using t to read input if ENTER is not pressed

Comment: That's the `-n` option. See the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html).

Comment: Even reading more than 1 character, your loop terminate before 6 seconds if you type ⏎

Comment: @InterLinked I updated my answer with asynchronous IO and messaging, to do exactly what you ask, that is: *Reading and handling the user input without affecting or disrupting your main loop task* timings.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written it, `read` expects a complete line:

- Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to continue
- Press <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to quit

When you just press `q` without Return, then you're not inputting a line so the variable is empty.

To be able to press a single key without Return, use `read -n 1`